# hadoop: hanging more than an hour to execute a dump of co-grouping in pig grunt

Tags: apache-pig

It's been more than an hour, and the job is still running, I guess it is dead already, what I was doing is very simple: 
I have two very small textfiles, and I imported them to hdfs already and would like to practice some pig latin operations. Here is what I did:
1. I created two relations, one for each
2. I created a co-grouping 
3. I tried to get a dump

The dump lasted for more than an hours now, I checked a few times in GUI, and found the same job has been ended and started again:
1. completed 50%
[image]

2. Started again and hanging
   [image]

btw: what the heck is Dr. Who showing in this screenshot (top right corner):

[image]

Comment: Could you provide output from the logs? It is nearly to impossible to tell what is going all. Your pig script will be useful as well.

Comment: Your node is turning to be unhealthy. Can you try the same thing with store ? May be your Java heap memory is running out. Can you also send the screenshot of the number of mappers and reducer, consider increasing the map-reduce percentage.(No of mappers to complete before reducer starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you may want to kill the job, the command is:

```
yarn -kill application_xxxxxx
```

and refresh the queue after the job is killed:

```
yarn rmadmin -refreshQueue
```